# How can I get unique arrays in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I got a fairly large array of arrays of length 2 (List[List[int, int]])
How can I unique arrays of them? Preferably without using different libraries

I've seen several solutions that use numpy, but I'm unlikely to be able to use this in olympiads

```
# Example input:
nums = [[2, 9], [3, 6], [9, 2], [6, 3]]

for i in nums:
    # some code here

# Output:
# nums = [[2, 9], [3, 6]]
```

I tried doing this but I guess it's not a very fast solution

```
# Example input:
nums = [[2, 9], [3, 6], [9, 2], [6, 3]]

unique = []
for i in nums:
    if sorted(i) not in unique:
        unique.append(sorted(i))

# Output:
print(unique) # [[2, 9], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: Are builtin libraries allowed?

Comment: Of course, there is no limit on built-in libraries

Comment: It seems that by 'unique' you mean 'order independant'; if so, turn your lists into sets (then back to lists if you want)

Comment: Is the order of elements in the outer list important or can the result be reordered (makes use of sets easier)?

Comment: Order doesn't important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with sets not being hashable, you can create a set of frozensets this way:

```
unique = {frozenset(i) for i in nums}
```

Then you can use whichever means to turn the results into the objects you want; for example:

```
unique = [list(i) for i in unique]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn each pair into a sorted `tuple`, put them all into a `set`, then turn that back into a list of lists.

```
>>> nums = [[2, 9], [3, 6], [9, 2], [6, 3]]
>>> {tuple(sorted(n)) for n in nums}
{(2, 9), (3, 6)}
>>> [list(t) for t in {tuple(sorted(n)) for n in nums}]
[[2, 9], [3, 6]]
```

The `tuple` is necessary because a set (which is created via the `{}` set comprehension expression) needs to contain hashable (immutable) objects.

Answer (score 0):

##### This answer is wrong. The `set` constructor does not sort its elements.

As @Swifty mentioned, you can use `set` to solve this problem. Send each pair through the `set` constructor to <s>sort the pair</s>, then convert it to `tuple` to make it hashable and use `set` again to remove duplicate tuples.

```
nums = [[2, 9], [3, 6], [9, 2], [6, 3]]

num_tuples = set(tuple(set(pair)) for pair in nums)

print(num_tuples)  # {(9, 2), (3, 6)}
```

**Warning:** As pointed out by @Samwise

> This is a little dodgy because you're assuming that `tuple(set(pair))` will deterministically create the same tuple ordering for any given set. This is probably true in practice (IIRC when you iterate over a set the items always come out in hash order, at least in CPython 3) but I'm not sure it's necessarily guaranteed by the Python spec. –

Comment: This is a little dodgy because you're assuming that `tuple(set(pair))` will deterministically create the same tuple ordering for any given set.  This is probably true in practice (IIRC when you iterate over a set the items always come out in hash order, at least in CPython 3) but I'm not sure it's necessarily guaranteed by the Python spec.

Comment: @Samwise Thanks for pointing it out. I'll add this as a warning to my answer.

Comment: @Samwise Nah, what they're really assuming is that *two* equal sets become equal tuples. Or in their words: *"Send each pair through the `set` constructor **to sort the pair**"* (emphasis mine). No idea why they're not using `sorted` for sorting. And their assumption is [wrong](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P680t1jBViE62kBHwSJWRyHaQkfBIDaWiwsoEV9SWpCTCpIuTi3RAHM0QKyCxMwiTU2FtPwiBRBTITNPAWSMJhdXQVFmXokGQqvm//8A).